# Color information missing from image processing

Tags: image, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library, rgba

I am learning to use numpy to manipulate images, but the color information was missing. I would like to find out why this happen.

My goal is to extract the difference between two images.

[image: Toy problem: Extract Welly from the graph.]

**Zero step: Load library**

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

**First step: Vectorize image with RGBA information**

```
img_org = Image.open('lena.png').convert('RGBA')
arr_org = np.array(img_org)
img_mod = Image.open('lena_modified.png').convert('RGBA')
arr_mod = np.array(img_mod)
arr_diff= np.zeros_like(arr_mod)
```

**Second step: Find out the difference between two images by logic rule**

```
for i in range(arr_mod.shape[0]) :
    for j in range(arr_mod.shape[1]) :
         if np.all(arr_mod[i, j]) == np.all(arr_org[i, j]):
             arr_diff[i,j] = (0,0,0,0)
         else :
             arr_diff[i, j] = arr_mod[i, j]
```

**Third step: Switch the image RGBA information back to image**

```
img_diff = Image.fromarray(arr_diff, 'RGBA')
img_diff.save('ans_two.png')
```

I hope to get colorful Welly from the modified Lena image. Like this 
[image]

However, I have no idea it only detect the outline/black part of the image. Any possible reason for this?

[image]

Disclaimer: This was a [homework](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wQ4H_JbFkFzKhLhBrRa_tfBJOhb2JAk5bBeMWf_I-7U/edit#slide=id.g1c9d4004ce_0_424) from a course offered in NTU during 2017 Spring. I am following this course and learn by myself. So you are NOT doing homework for me or anyone else. Thank you!

Comment: You can use the `absdiff` method to do that. Btw, if you can you should always provide the `expected` solution. `Difference` can mean a lot of things, strictly speaking it would be the difference of the pixel values differences or the combined differences.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did make a mistakes to take the difference between their pixel values and get funny results. The expected solution is the image in the middle, where there is a colorful welly in the bottom right. However, I am curious why I can only get the black outline while I am having RGBA pixel values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your RGB comparison should fix this:

```
 if np.array_equal(arr_mod[i, j],arr_org[i, j]):
         arr_diff[i,j] = (0,0,0,0)
     else :
         arr_diff[i, j] = arr_mod[i, j]
```

The issue is because np.all will return True if all values are True or their Truthiness value is true,the below example will return true in the interactive console

```
np.all([2,3,4,5]) == np.all([1,2,3,4])
```

This will return false in interactive console:

```
np.all([2,3,4,5]) == np.all([0,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain my mistake in more details. Just as @Abhijith pk explanation, `np.all` is not for comparing array value (here is pixel value). It is for checking whether all the value in the array is True.

For example, I check the bottom right corner `arr_org[511,511]=[ 75 18 18 255]` & `np.all([ 75 18 18 255])=True` means none of the RGBA element is zero.

However, for the black outline, its RGBA will be `[ 0 0 0 255]` & `np.all([0 0 0 255])=False` means some of the RGBA element is zero.

I am using the wrong code but I get the outline coincidentally. It is because in the original Lena image, most/all of the RGBA pixel values are nonzero and `np.all = True` ; while in the modified Lena image, the outline of Welly is black and has zeros in RGBA pixel values `np.all = False`. Since only the black outline has `false` output from `np.all`, I am lucky to get the outline by comparing `np.all`.

Again, using `np.all` is wrong for my case. Using `np.array_equal` is suggested. I am just trying to analyze the coincidence of getting black outline.